# How did they hide the JavaScript on this page?

Tags: javascript

I encountered a webpage that shows a popup, however, the only related JavaScript code I found on that page is the code below. What exactly does this code do and how does it hide the actual implementation (showing the popup)?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "/in.php?referer=" + escape(document.referrer);
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: I see no popup.  Are you talking about codeviewer.org itself, or the code you've pasted there?  Either way, I don't see anything hidden... be more specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17468822/2450730 here i wrote a way to hide some precious js.

Answer (score 0):

This code only inject a `<script>` tag.

When you look in the Chrome dev tools, you'll see the file referenced here in the *sources* tab.

This javascript file will have this name: "/in.php?referer=" (and `document.referrer` as value to the query string).

There's really nothing hidden, it's just that this way the javascript file is loaded asynchronously and won't block further script from loading/executing. This technique is often used by third party in order to leave the smallest footprint possible (google maps, twitter, facebook SDK, youtube, etc, etc).